# Make personnal Dataloader with PYTORCH

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, image-segmentation

I'm searching to create a personnal dataloader with a specific format to use Pytorch library, someone have an idea how can I do it ? I have follow Pytorch Tutorial but I don't find my answer!

I need a DataLoader that yields the tuples of the following format:
        (Bx3xHxW FloatTensor x, BxHxW LongTensor y, BxN LongTensor y_cls) where
        x - batch of input images,
        y - batch of groung truth seg maps,
        y_cls - batch of 1D tensors of dimensionality N: N total number of classes, 
        y_cls[i, T] = 1 if class T is present in image i, 0 otherwise

I hope that someone can unlock the problem .. :) Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to have a database derived from [`torch.utils.data.Dataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Dataset), where `__getitem__(index)` returns a tuple `(x, y, y_cls)` of the types you want, pytorch will take care of everything else.

```
from torch.utils import data

class MyTupleDataset(data.Dataset):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MyTupleDataset, self).__init__()
    # init your dataset here...

  def __getitem__(index):
    x = torch.Tensor(3, H, W)  # batch dim is handled by the data loader
    y = torch.Tensor(H, W).to(torch.long)
    y_cls = torch.Tensor(N).to(torch.long)
    return x, y, y_cls
```

That's it. Provide pytorch's  [`torch.utils.data.DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader) with `MyTupleDataset`  and you are done.

Comment: hi, so `data7 = MyTupleDataset(path_to_my_dataset) ` is enough to init a dataset we are agree ?

Comment: @Pythmania it all depends on how **you** implement `MyTupledataset`. As long as `__getitem__` returns a tuple, the `DataLoader` will make batches of three elements for your training.

Comment: What do you mean with the type of implementation for MyTupledataset ? an you give me an example please ? (I'm not an expert in Pytorch..!) I want just 1 class for informations :)

Comment: I've never been so close of my goal.. !